# How can I undo the locknut on this Shimano 105 hub

Tags: maintenance, shimano, hub, tools

I'm having trouble working out how to properly service this Shimano 105 rear hub. I've watched some videos, read Leonard Zinn's book and following [Park Tools' instructions](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/hub-overhaul-and-adjustment), but it doesn't help.

I've got a 15mm cone spanner around the cone (I think that's the part in the picture), but there are no flats of any size on the locknut.

I got some vise-grip pliers and managed to get it undone, but there must be an easier way!

[image: Flats on the cone (black), but not on the locknut (silver)]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I eventually worked out the easier way.

The locknut has a hole in the end which, in addition to taking the skewer when fitted, has a hex socket for a 5mm allen key. Turn the hex/allen key anti-clockwise relative to the cone spanner to undo.

[image: 15mm cone spanner and 5mm hex wrench on a Shimano 105 rear hub.]

Comment: Don't forget you can accept your own answer (since it is the correct answer)

Comment: A hex hidden inside a hole is not uncommon on race bike stuff - it looks sleeker and more aero than having flats on components, and flats have to be milled to look nice.  A hidden hex can be cast or pressed into the component, which is easier/quicker/cheaper during manufacture.   Great spotting BTW - I carry a bright torch/flashlight that is handy for these sorts of investigations

Comment: @WeiwenNg Thanks, it says I can do that tomorrow. I guess it can give other people a chance. :-)

Comment: @Criggie. Thanks, interesting background info.